# MultiDex - QBUser Quickblox class not found

Tags: android, quickblox, android-multidex

Trying to use Quickblox with my application. Multidex apk file gets generated properly.
But, there is a runtime issue while trying to get the QbUsers Class.

Following is the code:

```js
QBUsers.getUsersByIDs(usersIDs, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle params) {

                                // Save users
                                //

                                ((ApplicationSingleton) getApplication()).setDialogsUsers(users);
                                 Map<Integer, QBUser> usermap = ((ApplicationSingleton) getApplication()).getDialogsUsers();
                                for(Integer key:usermap.keySet()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(UnjoinClubActivity.this, "SenderFullName = " + usermap.get(key).getFullName() + "  " + usermap.get(key).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                // build list view
                                //?
                               // buildListView(dialogs);
                            }
```

Exception:

```html
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.quickblox.module.users.model.QBUser
            at com.sc.triumph.chatsingleton.ApplicationSingleton.setDialogsUsers(ApplicationSingleton.java:51)
            at com.sc.triumph.activities.UnjoinClubActivity$4$1.onSuccess(UnjoinClubActivity.java:394)
            at com.sc.triumph.activities.UnjoinClubActivity$4$1.onSuccess(UnjoinClubActivity.java:387)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.notifySuccess(Query.java:307)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query$VersionEntityCallback.completedWithResponse(Query.java:339)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:253)
            at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:38)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.quickblox.module.users.model.QBUser
            at com.sc.triumph.chatsingleton.ApplicationSingleton.setDialogsUsers(ApplicationSingleton.java:51)
            at com.sc.triumph.activities.UnjoinClubActivity$4$1.onSuccess(UnjoinClubActivity.java:394)
            at com.sc.triumph.activities.UnjoinClubActivity$4$1.onSuccess(UnjoinClubActivity.java:387)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.notifySuccess(Query.java:307)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query$VersionEntityCallback.completedWithResponse(Query.java:339)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:253)
            at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:38)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

If use the same function in a non multidex application it works fine.

Expecting help to understand what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

QBUsers - this class from QuickBlox Android SDK. Looks like SDK isn't included in the completed project. 
Please check dependency.